# Check if a nested property is defined in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript, undefined

Checking if simple variables are defined is made easy with `myVar?`

The question is, is there a nice way in CoffeeScript to check if a nested property is defined?

e.g.

```
if property.p.p.p.p?
  alert "Hello"
```

Throws a `ReferenceError` if `property.p.p.p` (or `property.p.p` | `property.p`) aren't defined.

Is this just something we have to recursively check, or is there a nice feature?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if property?.p?.p?.p?.p?
  alert "Hello"
```

Does what you want.

that translates to

```
var _ref, _ref1, _ref2;

if ((typeof property !== "undefined" && property !== null ? (_ref = property.p) != null ? (_ref1 = _ref.p) != null ? (_ref2 = _ref1.p) != null ? _ref2.p : void 0 : void 0 : void 0 : void 0) != null) {
  alert("Hello");
}
```

in JS.

The relevant piece of the docs:

> The accessor variant of the existential operator ?. can be used to soak up null references in a chain of properties. Use it instead of the dot accessor . in cases where the base value may be null or undefined. If all of the properties exist then you'll get the expected result, if the chain is broken, undefined is returned instead of the TypeError that would be raised otherwise.

Comment: This kind of thing is why coffeescript is great.